# Swift make the keyboard adapt with the devices screen

Tags: swift, keyboard, tableview, frame

So I want to learn swift and I am making this simple chat application ... and I have some problems controlling the keyboard.

- when the keyboard appears I want to push up the frame. If I wont do that I won't have access to my textfield. I found this two functions that are able to do that ... the problem is the devices screen aren't the same, and if i run the app on another device I have to change the size ...

   For example if I use iPhon6 i will use a 220 and if I use a 5 it is necessary 150 ... if I remember right. The dimension doesn't matter, the thing it is that aren't the same...

I think it must be a way to easily control  this future ... I'll appreciate any kind of help...

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillShow:"), name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil);
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillHide:"), name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil);
      }
      //hide keyboard and get down the view
      func keyboardWillHide(sender: NSNotification) {
        self.view.frame.origin.y += 200
      }
      //show keyboard and get up the view
      func keyboardWillShow(sender: NSNotification) {
        self.view.frame.origin.y -= 200
      }

      //hide keyboard if you tap the screen
      override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
      }
```

Thank you !

Comment: Use a scrollView . This will give you Smooth animation

Answer (score 1):

> Add a ScrollView  Try Below Code.

```
 @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
 @IBOutlet weak var onTopScrollView: UIView!
 var activeTextField: UITextField!
 var keyboardHeight: CGFloat = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillShow:"), name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil);
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillHide:"), name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil);
  }
  //hide keyboard and get down the view
  func keyboardWillHide(sender: NSNotification) {
    keyboardHeight = 0
    self.activeTextField = nil
    let contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero
    scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets
    scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets
    scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 0)
  }
  //show keyboard and get up the view
  func keyboardWillShow(sender: NSNotification) {
    let info : NSDictionary = sender.userInfo!
    let kbSize = (info.objectForKey(UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey)?.CGRectValue() as CGRect!).size
    let contentInsets: UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, kbSize.height, 0.0);
    keyboardHeight = kbSize.height
    println(keyboardHeight)

    scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;

    var aRect = self.onTopScrollView.frame
    aRect.size.height -= keyboardHeight;
    if (!CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, self.activeTextField.frame.origin) ) {
        var rect = onTopScrollView.convertRect(CGRectZero, fromView: self.activeTextField)
        rect.size = self.activeTextField.frame.size
        //print(CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, self.activeTextField.frame.origin))
        self.scrollView.scrollRectToVisible(rect, animated: true)
    }
  }

   override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
}

// handle TextField Delegates 
 func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    self.activeTextField = textField
}
```

Comment: what is `onTopScrollView` ?

Comment: @IBOutlet weak var onTopScrollView: UIView! its outlet you put on scroll view